# How to remove "out of stock" variation options from size dropdown in woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

I'm using woocommerce to display products and their variations. I have a variation called 'Size' for all of the products. Some of the variations are out of stock, but these are still showing in the select dropdown. See the attached image:

[image: Stock options dropdown - size variation]

How do I remove or blank out a variation from being selected if a variation is 'Out of Stock'? I've tried using 'Hide Out of Stock' in the WooCommerce settings though this made no difference.

Comment: Are you using a child-theme? If so, you might try overriding the related template, and filter out the values in "the loop".

Answer (score 0):

Initially. It should be said that WooCommerce is considered a plugin and therefore your question could probably be flagged as 'Off-topic'. This (however) is such a bullshit and self-deprecating for this StackExchange, so I'll answer it anyway. :-)

But next time you have a WooCommerce-question, you should ask it on StackOverflow (apparantly).

---

My first thought is that you could have 'Backorders' enabled on your variations. Either that or that you have stock enabled on either the variation-level and/or your product, and that somehow makes it possible for customers to buy something that is out of stock.

If this isn't the answer, then perhaps try to add a screenshot of one of the problematic variations and also the 'Inventory'-tab of the product.